# Disable custom image size creation for plugins

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using a plugin which creates a custom image size with this name `featured_large` and it is creating this image for every image I have.

There is no option in the media section to disable this and the plugin does not give the option to disable it as well, how can I disable creating this image size without modifying the plugin?

Comment: just remove it https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_image_size

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'remove_plugin_image_sizes');

function remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('featured_large');
}
```

The code needs to be added to the file functions.php